# Styling text in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I know you can style text by using the `+` operator to concatenate `Text` views, but I’m trying to do this, and it seems something is erasing the styling:

```swift
struct MyView : View {
    var body: some View {
        …
        textFor(notification: self.notification)
            .foregroundColor(Color("notification-title"))
            .font(.custom("Inter", size: 14.0).weight(.regular))
    }
    
    func
    textFor(notification inNote: WNNotification)
        -> some View
    {
        if <condition1>
        {
            if let listingID = inNote.listingID
            {
                return Text("Your listing for ")
                        + Text(listingID).bold()
                        + Text(" was ")
                        + Text("canceled.").bold()
            }
            else
            {
                return Text("Your listing was ")
                        + Text("canceled.").bold()
            }
        }
        else if <condition2>
        {
            return Text("Your order for ")
                    + Text("product").bold()
                    + Text(" has been shipped.")
        }
        
        return Text("\(inNote.message)")
    }
}
```

I feel like this should work, in that the inner styling takes precedence over the outer styling, but it doesn't seem to be working like that. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: yes it seems the inner styling takes precedence over the outer styling 
for the "foregroundColor(...)" but not for the "font(...)". Maybe because Font is a late-binding token. You may have to style each Text, eg: Text("canceled.").font(.custom("Inter", size: 14.0).weight(.bold))

Comment: Yeah, I was just experimenting with that. It does seem to work to do that, but wow. This behavior makes no sense. I wrote a bug to Apple about it.

Comment: It's very confusing, what it's actually doing. Looking at it in the view navigator, it makes no sense.